# Jquery Compare original state of checkbox with change state

Tags: jquery, checkbox

what i want to do is that, 
i want to hold the value of the checkbox(original state) and then on checkbox state change check if the state is not original state then show a textarea.

what i have done till now

```
<script>
    var status = $('#status').val();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        status = $('#status').is(":checked");
        $('#status').on('click', function() {
           if( $('#status').is(":checked")!=status){
               $('#mandatory').html('*');
           }else{
               alert("else");
               $('#mandatory').html('');
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

problem i am facing is that it is not comparing two values.

Comment: Add your HTML code also

Comment: Is `var status = $('#status').val();` executed before the element exists on the page?

Comment: When you want to display? When it is checked?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/txbL6k67/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks issue solved. sad i was not able to do this, it was simple. but thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var status = $('#status').is(":checked"); // Get default status

    $('#status').on('change', function() {
        // On change the state of checkbox
        var html = ($(this).is(':checked') !== status) ? '*' : '';
        $('#mandatory').html(html).toggle(!!html); // Set the value and toggle(show/hide) the textarea
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var default_status = $('#status_check').is(":checked"); 

    $('#status_check').on('change', function() {
        
        if($(this).is(':checked') == default_status ) {
           // Hide Text box
            $('#field').hide();
        } else {
            // Show text box
             $('#field').show();
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="store_value" id="status_check"><br />
<input type="text" id="field" class="field" style="display:none;" />
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avinashz/6umg078w/)